# Kill process on the left side of a pipe

Tags: bash, process, pipe

I have the following in bash:

foo | bar

I want `foo` to die when the script is terminated (using a TERM signal). Unfortunately, none of them dies. I tried this:

```
exec foo | bar
```

This achieved absolutely nothing. Then I tried this:

```
function run() {
    "$@" &
    pid=$!
    trap "kill $pid" EXIT
    wait
}

run foo | bar
```

Again, nothing. Now I have one more process, and none of them dies when I terminate the parent.

Comment: running `foo|bar` in a separate process group may help. [related](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128682)

Comment: Could you please give us an example? `bash -c 'sleep 50 | sleep 50' & kill $!` will properly terminate both sleeps...

Comment: @Camusensei No, it does not. Try this: `bash -c 'sleep 50 | sleep 50' & sleep 1; kill $!`

Comment: Indeed. I changed my answer to a working one, please review it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By killing the whole process group instead of just `bash` (the parent), you can send the kill signal to all children as well.
Syntax examples are:

```
kill -SIGTERM -$!
kill -- -$!
```

Example:

```
bash -c 'sleep 50 | sleep 40' & sleep 1; kill -SIGTERM -$!; wait; ps -ef | grep -c sleep
[1] 14683
[1]+  Terminated              bash -c 'sleep 50 | sleep 40'
1
```

Note that `wait` here waits for bash to be effectively killed which takes some milliseconds.
Also note that the final result (1) is the 'grep sleep' itself. A result of 3 would show that this did not work as two additional sleep processes would still be running.

The `kill` manual mentions:

```
-n
where n is larger than 1. All processes in process group n are signaled.
When an argument of the form '-n' is given, and it is meant to denote a
process group, either the signal must be specified first, or the argument
must be preceded by a '--' option, otherwise it will be taken as the signal
to send.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a named pipe, which makes it easier to get the process ID of `foo` specifically.

```
trap 'kill $foo_pid; rm -f foo_out' EXIT

mkfifo foo_out
foo > foo_out & foo_pid=$!
bar < foo_out
```